# Why i should generate texture in initializeGL qt

Tags: qt, opengl

I'm trying to draw yuv image using Qt OpenGL.

I've create a 'CameraSurface_GL' class inherited from QGLWidget, drawing yuv image received from ip camera.

I introduce my code here.

```
#include "camerasurface_gl.h"
#include <QtWidgets>
#include <QtGui>
#include <QOpenGLFunctions_3_0>


const char* YUV420P_VS = ""
  "#version 330\n"
  ""
  "uniform mat4 u_pm;"
  "uniform vec4 draw_pos;"
  ""
  "const vec2 verts[4] = vec2[] ("
  "  vec2(-0.5,  0.5), "
  "  vec2(-0.5, -0.5), "
  "  vec2( 0.5,  0.5), "
  "  vec2( 0.5, -0.5)  "
  ");"
  ""
  "const vec2 texcoords[4] = vec2[] ("
  "  vec2(0.0, 1.0), "
  "  vec2(0.0, 0.0), "
  "  vec2(1.0, 1.0), "
  "  vec2(1.0, 0.0)  "
  "); "
  ""
  "out vec2 v_coord; "
  ""
  "void main() {"
  "   vec2 vert = verts[gl_VertexID];"
  "   vec4 p = vec4((0.5 * draw_pos.z) + draw_pos.x + (vert.x * draw_pos.z), "
  "                 (0.5 * draw_pos.w) + draw_pos.y + (vert.y * draw_pos.w), "
  "                 0, 1);"
  "   gl_Position = u_pm * p;"
  "   v_coord = texcoords[gl_VertexID];"
  "}"
  "";


const char* YUV420P_FS = ""
 "#version 330\n"
  "uniform sampler2D y_tex;"
  "uniform sampler2D u_tex;"
  "uniform sampler2D v_tex;"
  "in vec2 v_coord;"
  "layout( location = 0 ) out vec4 fragcolor;"
  ""
    "const vec3 R_cf = vec3(1,  0.000000,  1.13983);"
    "const vec3 G_cf = vec3(1, -0.39465, -0.58060);"
    "const vec3 B_cf = vec3(1,  2.03211,  0.000000);"
  "const vec3 offset = vec3(-0.0625, -0.5, -0.5);"
  ""
  "void main() {"
  "  float y = texture(y_tex, v_coord).r;"
  "  float u = texture(u_tex, v_coord).r;"
  "  float v = texture(v_tex, v_coord).r;"
  "  vec3 yuv = vec3(y,u,v);"
  "  yuv += offset;"
  "  fragcolor = vec4(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);"
  "  fragcolor.r = dot(yuv, R_cf);"
  "  fragcolor.g = dot(yuv, G_cf);"
  "  fragcolor.b = dot(yuv, B_cf);"
  "}"
  "";

CameraSurface_GL::CameraSurface_GL(QWidget *parent) :
    QGLWidget(parent)
  ,vid_w(0)
  ,vid_h(0)
  ,win_w(0)
  ,win_h(0)
  ,vao(0)
  ,y_tex(0)
  ,u_tex(0)
  ,v_tex(0)
  ,vert(0)
  ,frag(0)
  ,prog(0)
  ,u_pos(-1)
  ,textures_created(false)
  ,shader_created(false)
{
    qRegisterMetaType<YUVFrame>("YUVFrame");
    m_ipCamera = new IpCamera;

    connect(m_ipCamera, SIGNAL(frameChanged(YUVFrame)), this, SLOT(slotFrameChanged(YUVFrame)));

    m_frameCount = 0;
    m_setup = 0;
}

CameraSurface_GL::~CameraSurface_GL()
{
    glDeleteTextures(1, &y_tex);
    glDeleteTextures(1, &u_tex);
    glDeleteTextures(1, &v_tex);

    glDeleteProgram(prog);
}

void CameraSurface_GL::openCamera(QString ipAddress, QString userName, QString password)
{
    if(m_ipCamera->isRunning())
        m_ipCamera->close();

    bool opend = m_ipCamera->open(ipAddress, userName, password);
    if(opend == false)
        return;
}

void CameraSurface_GL::closeCamera()
{
    m_ipCamera->close();
}

void CameraSurface_GL::slotFrameChanged(YUVFrame frame)
{
    m_yuvFrame = frame;
        update();
}

void CameraSurface_GL::setup_gl(int width, int height)
{
    vid_w = width;
    vid_h = height;

    if(!vid_w || !vid_h) {
      printf("Invalid texture size.\n");
      return;
    }

    if(!setupTextures()) {
      return;
    }

    if(!setupShader()) {
      return;
    }

    glGenVertexArrays(1, &vao);

    return;
}

void CameraSurface_GL::resize_gl(int width, int height)
{
    win_w = width;
    win_h = height;

    pm.setToIdentity();
    pm.ortho(0, win_w, win_h, 0, 0.0, 100.0f);

    glUseProgram(prog);
    glUniformMatrix4fv(glGetUniformLocation(prog, "u_pm"), 1, GL_FALSE, pm.data());
}



void CameraSurface_GL::initializeGL()
{
    initializeOpenGLFunctions();
    glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);

    setup_gl(1920, 1080);
}


void CameraSurface_GL::paintGL()
{
    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    if(m_yuvFrame.yuvData.size())
    {
        setYPixels((unsigned char*)m_yuvFrame.yuvData.data(), yuvFrame.width);
        setUPixels((unsigned char*)m_yuvFrame.yuvData.data() + yuvFrame.width * yuvFrame.height, yuvFrame.width / 2);
        setVPixels((unsigned char*)m_yuvFrame.yuvData.data() + yuvFrame.width * yuvFrame.height * 5 / 4, yuvFrame.width / 2);

        glBindVertexArray(vao);
        glUseProgram(prog);

        QRect frameRect = rect();

        glUniform4f(u_pos, frameRect.left(), frameRect.top(), frameRect.width(), frameRect.height());

        glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, y_tex);

        glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, u_tex);

        glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE2);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, v_tex);

        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);
    }
}


void CameraSurface_GL::resizeGL(int width, int height)
{
    glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
    resize_gl(width, height);
}

bool CameraSurface_GL::setupTextures()
{
    if(textures_created) {
      printf("Textures already created.\n");
      return false;
    }

    glGenTextures(1, &y_tex);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, y_tex);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_R8, vid_w, vid_h, 0, GL_RED, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, NULL);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

    glGenTextures(1, &u_tex);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, u_tex);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_R8, vid_w/2, vid_h/2, 0, GL_RED, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, NULL);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

    glGenTextures(1, &v_tex);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, v_tex);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_R8, vid_w/2, vid_h/2, 0, GL_RED, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, NULL);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

    textures_created = true;

    return true;
}

bool CameraSurface_GL::setupShader()
{
    if(shader_created) {
      printf("Already creatd the shader.\n");
      return false;
    }

    vert = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(vert, 1, &YUV420P_VS, 0);
    glCompileShader(vert);

    frag = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(frag, 1, &YUV420P_FS, 0);
    glCompileShader(frag);

    prog = glCreateProgram();
    glAttachShader(prog, vert);
    glAttachShader(prog, frag);
    glLinkProgram(prog);

    glUseProgram(prog);
    glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(prog, "y_tex"), 0);
    glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(prog, "u_tex"), 1);
    glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(prog, "v_tex"), 2);

    u_pos = glGetUniformLocation(prog, "draw_pos");

    return true;
}


void CameraSurface_GL::setYPixels(uint8_t* pixels, int stride)
{
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, y_tex);
    glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ROW_LENGTH, stride);
    glTexSubImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 0, 0, vid_w, vid_h, GL_RED, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixels);
}

void CameraSurface_GL::setUPixels(uint8_t* pixels, int stride)
{
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, u_tex);
    glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ROW_LENGTH, stride);
    glTexSubImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 0, 0, vid_w/2, vid_h/2, GL_RED, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixels);
}

void CameraSurface_GL::setVPixels(uint8_t* pixels, int stride)
{
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, v_tex);
    glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ROW_LENGTH, stride);
    glTexSubImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 0, 0, vid_w/2, vid_h/2, GL_RED, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixels);
}
```

I call 'setup' function in initializeGL, using static parameter 1920, 1080.

This is not my idea.

I want to call 'setup' function when received yuv frame from ip camera, so I changed my code to the following.

```
void CameraSurface_GL::initializeGL()
{
    initializeOpenGLFunctions();
    glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
}

void CameraSurface_GL::slotFrameChanged(YUVFrame frame)
{
    if(m_setup == 0)
    {
        setup_gl(frame.width, frame.height);
        resize_gl(frame.width, frame.height);
        m_setup = 1;
    }

    m_yuvFrame = frame;
        update();
}
```

At this time, I can't show drawn image on view.

Why I receive the issue?

Can't I call 'setup' function in other place, in not initializeGL?

Comment: Where do you set up the vertex attrib pointers?

Comment: Hi, thanks your replying. I haven't  the setup vertex attrib pointers.  
I've appeded shader programe source code. Reference it.